# Regex for single digit catches two digit numbers?

Tags: php, regex

This regex catches two digit nubers:

if I have y11 it will still catch it, how to match only y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9 ?? After the digit there might be a blank space or a letter or a dot.

```
preg_replace('/y([1-9]{1})/', 'y0$1', $string)
```

Comment: `[1-9]` will not catch `0` though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would match on the pattern `y\d(?!\d)`, which matches `y` followed by a single digit, which itself is not followed by another digit.

```php
$string = "y2";
echo $string . "\n";
$string = preg_replace("/y(\d)(?!\d)/", "y0$1", $string);
echo $string;
```

This prints:

```
y2
y02
```

Explanation of regex:

```regex
y       the letter 'y'
(\d)    a single digit (capture it)
(?!\d)  assert that what follows is either a non digit character OR
        the end of the input
```

Answer (score 5):

You can omit `{1}` and `[1-9]` does not match a 0. The pattern partially matches for example `y1` in `y11` as the pattern is unanchored.

You can match a `y` followed by a digit and assert either a space, dot or letter or the end of the string.

```
\by\K\d(?=[\h\p{L}.]|$)
```

The pattern matches

- `\by` Match y preceded by a word boundary
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `\d` Match a single digit 0-9
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is

  - `[\h\p{L}.]` Match either a horizontal whitespace char, any letter or a dot
  - `|` Or
  - `$` End of string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aXtTEk/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/sDScE)

In the replacement use the full match preceded by a `0`

```
$pattern = "/\by\K\d(?=[\h\p{L}.]|$)/";
$strings = [
    "y0",
    "y1$",
    "y2H",
    "y3.",
    "y9 ",
    "y10",
    "y09  y3 ay9"
];

foreach ($strings as $s) {
    echo preg_replace($pattern, "0$0", $s) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
y00
y1$
y02H
y03.
y09 
y10
y09  y03 ay9
```

Comment: Thank you, very much! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
^[a-zA-Z]\d[\s.a-zA-Z]?$
```

OR you want to match exactly values starting from `y` then change above to:

```
^y\d[\s.a-zA-Z]?$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/oVl4y8/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^                   ##Mentioning ^ caret sign to denote starting of value.
[a-zA-Z]            ##Checking 1 alphabet(small/capital letters) here.
\d                  ##Matching 1 single digit here.
[\s.a-zA-Z]?        ##Checking either space OR DOT or small or capital letter to match, this is keep optional.
$                   ##Mentioning end of the value here.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[a-zA-Z]+(\d)([,\sa-zA-Z.]|\b)
```

- `[a-zA-Z]+` Match a character or characters.
- `(\d)` to match a single digit. Add them in a capturing group to replace later.
- `([,\sa-zA-Z.]|\b)` to match the text immediately followed by this comma, space or word boundary or letters.
- Make sure to add `$2` too to preserve it's initial representation while replacing.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = 'y0, y1, y2, y03, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9, y99, y101';

$str = preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]+(\d)([,\sa-zA-Z.]|\b)/','y0$1$2',$str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: How do you know that the OP expects comma, whitespace, or word boundary after the digit?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I updated my answer. OP has stated in his post _After the digit there might be a blank space or a letter or a dot._

Answer (score 1):

How about this

`^y(\d)[A-Za-z\s\.]?$`

https://regex101.com/r/FxQA0T/1

Or

`^y(\d)[^\d]?$`